# How to get a static logger from a fragment in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, companion-object

**Here is what I want to do:**

I have an app with basically no GUI whatsoever, just a lot of stuff going on in the background (app is basically just a LAN remote control for the camera, so I have camera classes, network classes and so on running in the background.
However, I want to have a simple `TextView` on my GUI, that will display some sort of log. All of my classes should have access to this log and add/write stuff. Since my GUI consists only of a single textview, I don't want to bother with MVVM, which would be my go-to GUI pattern.

**What I have so far:**

For the TextView, I created a Fragment:

```
class GUIFragment : Fragment(R.layout.gui_fragment) {


    // other class members
    private lateinit var logger : Logger

    private var _binding: GuiFragmentBinding? = null
    private val guiBinding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        retainInstance = true
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        //set up bindings
        _binding = GuiFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        guiBinding.logviewer.movementMethod = ScrollingMovementMethod()
        logger = Logger(guiBinding.logviewer)
        return guiBinding.root


    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

    // other logic 

    companion object {
        fun getLogger() : Logger?{
            return null // or my logger instance
        }
    }
}
```

The idea here is to have a static method, which returns either the fragments `logger` instance or null (since the GUI doesn't change at all, it should in reality always return the `logger` instance. The `logger` itself is a member of the fragment and gets the bound `TextView` passed to it's constructor. However, I suppose companion objects have no access to class members (which makes sense, since those are none-static)? Should my `logger` member be static too, but then how should I pass the `TextView` to it?

For completeness sake here is the `Logger` class too:

```
class Logger (_tv : TextView) {

    private val maxLogLines = 100
    private val tv = _tv

    suspend fun log(msg: String?) = withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
        var logtext = tv.text.toString()
        logtext = logtext.plus("${msg}\n")
        var split = logtext.split("\n")


        if (split.count() >= maxLogLines) {
            logtext = split.slice(1 until (maxLogLines - 1)).joinToString("\n")
        }
        tv.text = logtext
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just pass `Logger` to the class which need it, like any other dependency?

Comment: @al3c yes absolutely. I just thought, instead of passing around the logger reference, having one central access point would be nicer...